# XQuery, fn:id and BD eXist

Tags: xml, database, xquery

Does "fn:id" function return IDREFS when it is used in a FLOWER xquery with eXists database?

I can't get any example... :(

Answer (score 1):

[blog entry](http://xqueryxpath.tumblr.com/) about [fn:id](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-id)

Answer (score 0):

fn:id returns as sequence of nodes or empty sequence.  From the [eXist documentation](http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/functions/xpath-functions/id):

> id($idrefs as xs:string*) element()*
>
> Returns the sequence of element nodes
> that have an ID value matching the
> value of one or more of the IDREF
> values supplied in $idrefs. If none is
> matching or $idrefs is the empty
> sequence, returns the empty sequence.